# Expected number of coin tosses until a run of $k$ successive heads occurs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose each coin toss is independent, what is the expected number of coin tosses until a run of "k" successive heads occur? Tried finding a recursive expression to solve the problem but got completely lost.

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials).

Comment: and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364038/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-get-five-consecutive-heads

Answer (score 5):

Let $R_k$ be the number of tosses until the first run of $k$ heads and $E_k := E(R_k)$. The event that the first run of $k$ heads appears is the disjoint union of the event that the first run of $k-1$ heads appears followed by a head and the event that the first run of $k-1$ heads appears followed by a tail followed eventually by a run of $k$ heads.

If the probability of heads is $p$, then using the properties of conditional expectation

$$E_k = p(E_{k-1} + 1)+ (1-p)(E_{k-1} + 1 + E_k)$$

and

$$E_k = \frac1{p}(E_{k-1} +1).$$

Since $E_1 = 1/p$, we can solve recursively to obtain

$$E_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k}p^{-j}= \frac{(\frac1{p})^k-1}{1-p}.$$