# Expected number of tosses of getting $n$ heads in a row

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

I'm looking at a proof by induction of getting $n$ heads in a row, and I'm not understanding what law they are using in this proof.

To start, let's define $f(n)$ as the number of tosses needed to get $n$ heads in a row. The formula is given to be $E[f(n)] = 2^{n+1} - 2$, and we are asked to prove this formula by induction.

The step I am getting lost is where they assume this formula holds for $n=k$ and use this to show that it holds for $n=k+1$. The notes wrote that "Conditioned on the previous state (k heads in a row), there is a 0.5 probability it will toss another head and thus go to the state with k+1 heads in a row and the process stops, or if it tosses a tail, with probability 0.5, it goes to the starting state. Therefore
$$
E[f(k+1)] = E[f(k)] + 0.5\cdot 1 + 0.5E[f(k+1)].
$$

I don't understand where this equation came from. It seems to be a form of the law of total expectation, but it's not clear to me what the conditional events are.

The way I learned law of total expectation is the following:

$$
E[X] = \sum_i E[X|A_i] P(A_i)
$$
for disjoint events $A_i$. What are the $A_i$'s in this problem? Is it (1) Starting from k heads in a roll and tossing a head (2) starting from k heads in a roll and tossing a tail?

So something like the following?
$$
E[f(k+1)] = E[f(k+1) | \kappa, T]P(\kappa, T) + E[f(k+1) | \kappa, H]P(\kappa, H)
$$
where $\kappa$ is the event of having $k$ heads in a row, and $T$ and $H$ are the events tossing a tail and a head.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376270/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364038/321264

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected number of coin tosses to land n heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155104/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-land-n-heads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get $k + 1$ heads in a row, you first need to get $k$ heads in a row.

By definition, in $f(k)$ tosses, you get $k$ heads in a row, so $f(k + 1) - f(k)$ is the number of tosses between getting $k$ heads and getting $k + 1$ heads.

There are two possibilities for the $(f(k) + 1)$-th toss, head or tail. These are the two disjoint events you are looking for. We denote them by $H$ and $T$.

Using the formula of total expectation, we will have $$E[f(k + 1) - f(k)] = E[f(k + 1) - f(k)|H] \times 0.5 + E[f(k + 1) - f(k)|T] \times 0.5.$$

Now if $H$ happens, then we obviously have $f(k + 1) - f(k) = 1$, hence $E[f(k + 1) - f(k)|H] = 1$.

If $T$ happens, then the first $f(k) + 1$ tosses are all wasted, so that $E[f(k + 1) - (f(k) + 1)|T] = E[f(k + 1)]$.

Hence we get $$E[f(k + 1)] = E[f(k)] + 1 \times 0.5 + (1 + E[f(k + 1)]) \times 0.5.$$ This is slightly different from the formula in your question. I doubt that it's a typo in your source material.

Solving this recurrence relation gives us the willing result.

Comment: Hmm actually, it does seem there is a typo in my source, but they had the correct answer in the end, so the error didn't propagate through. 

Also, is there a typo in your equation under "If $T$ happens, ...."? You have $E[f(k+1) - (f(k)+1)|T] = E[f(k+1)]$. It should just be $E[f(k+1) - f(k)|T] = 1 + E[f(k+1)]$?

Comment: Is there a way to think about this problem without thinking of the difference between 2 random variables, in this case $f(k+1) - f(k)$? The notes state "conditioning on the state of having $k$ heads in a row" but it doesn't seem like your answer is conditioning on that, or am I mistaken?

Comment: My answer conditions on the outcome of the $(f(k)+1)$-th toss, which is exactly the status when you have $k$ heads in a row.

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking that it wasn't an explicit condition because it wasn't written after the $\big |$. Could you also address my first comment on a possible typo?

Comment: I don't quite understand your first comment... The two lines are equivalent. I can confirm that there is no typo in my answer.