# What's the expected number of times I have to roll two die until they both sum $7$?

Tags: probability, expectation, dice

Here is my guess: the probability of summing $7$ on two rolls is $\frac 16$. This means if I repeat the experiment many times I'll roll $7$ one sixth of them (approximately). Hence,

$$N \cdot \bigg(\cfrac 16\bigg) \cdot 7 = 7$$

where $N$ is the total number of rolls. That gives me a total number of $6$ rolls on average to sum $7$.

I'm not quite sure so I'm all open to suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The probability that a pair of dice add to seven is indeed $\frac{1}{6}$.  The intuitive interpretation of the probability here is infact the correct one, that on average one in six rolls will give a sum of seven, and it so happens that indeed $\frac{1}{p}$ or in this case $\frac{1}{1/6}$, i.e. $6$ is the expected number of rolls until you get a sum of seven.

Comment: Sounds like a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) stopping at the first success.

Comment: If you want a more formal proof of this, consider reading my answer to a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196452/expected-value-of-the-number-of-flips-until-the-first-head/1196478#1196478).

Comment: @AntoniParellada more easily described as a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: @JMoravitz Agree.

Comment: I don't know why you are multiplying by seven. $7$ really has no **numeric** purpose in this question. You could have similarly asked about how many times you roll until you get snake eyes or a total of eight. That event is also probability $\frac{1}{6},$ and the expected rolls until you get that event is the same. So your multiplication is mysterious.

Comment: I mean, if p=1/6 then I'll expect to succeed N/6 times so I then multiply by 7 to work out the expected value.

Comment: @Juan123 If, as you say, you "expect to succeed $N/6$ times", then what does "the total of excepted value" mean and why do you find it multiplying by $7$?

Comment: In case anybody landing here wondered about geometric v. negative binomial, the result is exactly the same. For the geometric distribution (probability that the first occurrence of success requires k independent trials, each with success probability p.), the expectation $E(X)=1/p=6.$ The negative binomial counts the total number of trials before $r$ successes - $r=1$ in this case - with the probability of failure $q= 1-p=5/6,$ as $\frac{r}{(1-q)}=6.$ I agree that NB is unnecessarily complex for this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Did you mean to imply that the probability of rolling snake eyes is 1/6? Because it is not.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? "snake eyes or a total of eight." @ale10ander

Comment: Yes, the probability of getting snake eyes is 1/36 and that of a sum eight is 5/36. Neither is 1/6. Your statement was ambiguous - snarking others for it doesn't help. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I apologize; I initially interpreted your comment as two scenarios, both equal to 1/6: the first being snake eyes, the second being a total of 8. I now understand you to mean the one scenario of either snake eyes or a total of 8.

Comment: @Nij The probability of getting snake eyes or eight is $1/6$.

Answer (score 21):

If $X$ is the number of rolls to get $7$ then the expected (or average) value of $X$ satisfies:

$$E(X)=1+\frac{5}{6}E(X)$$

That is, we always start with one roll, and $5/6$ of the time, we just start all over again. So $E(X)=6.$

---

Technically, as Heinrich comments below, this only proves that either $E(X)=6$ or $E(X)=+\infty.$ You might actually need some trick to prove that the expected value must be finite.

Comment: Maybe there's no **need** to use power series, but there could just be the joy of power series to motivate us to use them. ;-)

Comment: Even better, if you know the probability is 1/6 then you just take the inverse to get 6 immediately.

Comment: Sure, but this explains *why* you can do that. @RobinSaunders

Comment: This assumes that the expected value of $X$ exists and is finite.

Comment: Well, the expected value exists, because any positive random variable has an expected value. However, you are correct it might be infinite, @heinrich5991

Comment: Just a guess is all, but if the expected value was indeed infinite in this case, wouldn't they diverge at the same rate? That is, if we let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1+5x/6$, wouldn't we expect the limit of $f(x) / g(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity to be equal to $1$?

Answer (score 14):

The probability of doing it after one roll is $1/6$, in two is $5/6 \times 1/6$, in three $(5/6)^2 1/6$ and so on ... we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(7)=1 \times \frac{1}{6} + 2 \times \frac{5}{6} \times\frac{1}{6} + 3 \times \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 \times\frac{1}{6}+\cdots = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^i \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now recall that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i x^{i-1} =\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(7)= \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{i-1} =\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{5}{6})^2}=6
\end{eqnarray*}
So the expected value is $\color{red}{6}$ as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\frac 56)^{i-1}$?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that it will take on average $6$ rolls, IF we are considering the tossing of both dice together as one roll. If we let $X$ be the number of rolls until we reach a sum of $7$, then we can model this using a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

You have already calculated that the probability of rolling a sum of $7$ to be $1/6$. Therefore the probability that you don't roll a sum of $7$ is $5/6$.

The distribution for the probability that it will take $k$ rolls to reach a sum of $7$ will be $$P(X=k) = (5/6)^{k-1} * (1/6)$$

You can then find the mean of this distribution, which turns out to be $$\frac{1}{1/6} =6$$  I'll leave the derivation of this for you to look up :)

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that a pair of rolls  counts as one experiment.