# Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

How can I find a formula for $$\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k$$

I'd also appreciate if someone could indicate some materials about this subject.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)2^{k+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k2^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{k+1}$

Comment: **Hint:** Use with [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series): $(k-1)2^{k+1}-(k-2)2^k=k2^k$

Comment: In my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196452/expected-value-of-the-number-of-flips-until-the-first-head/1196478#1196478) I show how to derive the formula for the related sum of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{p}$.  With a few tweaks and some algebraic manipulation by taking the difference of two such series it can be modified to your sum.

Comment: This does not seem like a duplicate. That question is about a convergent series and this is about the partial sum of a divergent series.

Comment: That is, the partial sum is $(n-1)2^{n+1}+2$, and this diverges as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k}=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right)$$

Put $x=2$.