# How many times on average do we have to draw to get winning ticket?

Tags: probability

> On lottery there are $100$ losing tickets and $20$ winning tickets.
> We draw with return, until we draw winning ticket.
> How many times on average do we have to draw to get winning ticket?
>
> What's the standard deviation?

---

So its obviously geometric distribution (Bernoulli)

Chance to draw winning ticket is $\frac{1}{6}$

I can put it into the formula but I don't know how to calculate the average.

What am I supposed to put as random variable $i$?

$P(X=i)=(1-\frac{1}{6})^{i-1}\frac{1}{6}$

**Answer:**

Formula for computing the expected value of a geometric distribution = $\frac{1}{p}$

$p=\frac{1}{6}$

$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}}=6$

6 times on average untill we draw winning ticket.

Comment: Do you know a formula for computing the expected value of a geometric distribution?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I didn't know but I quickly googled it. Formula would be 1/p?
Then the answer is $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}}=6$. Seems too simple.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196452/expected-value-of-the-number-of-flips-until-the-first-head/1196478#1196478 for a proof.  The result for the standard deviation should also be readily available on searching and proofs for that also scattered around this site.

Comment: Its beyond me why its not included in my lecture pdf and yet it was on the test.
This task is from my last exam that I didn't pass, If I have gotten it right I would pass with minimum required... Thanks for help guys.