# Expected value of probability game. Should you play this game?

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed until heads ($H$) appears but is tossed only up to a maximum of $10^6$ times. If $H$ appears on the $n$-th  toss, the player gets $2^{n-1}$ dollars. If all tosses are tails $(T)$ then you lose all of your money. The entrance fee for this game is $10^5$ dollars. Should you play this game?

I have tried to look at similar problems like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196452/expected-value-of-the-number-of-flips-until-the-first-head) but I am not sure how to make the connection from: #of tosses until first heads to the chance that I will get at least one heads in the $10^6$ tosses and then subsequently turning that into an expected value. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you think that $P(\text{only tails})=10^{-6}$?

Comment: $P(\text{only tails})=2^{-10^{6}} \approx 10^{-301030}$

Comment: @drhab I just realized we don't have $10^6$ outcomes but we have. $2^{(10^6 )}$ outcomes. My bad.

Comment: Well, as @Henry made clear that there are much more outcomes. For each of the $10^6$ throws there are two possibilities.

Comment: It is a bit of a nonsense.  Your calculations will lead to you assuming you might win many many orders of magnitude more than all the money and wealth in the universe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: Assume the first head occurs on the $N$'th toss (so $N$ is a random variable). Let $X$ be the amount of dollars gained. Then
$$
X = \begin{cases} 2^{N-1} & N\le 10^6 \\ 0 & N > 10^6 \end{cases} ,
$$
and we want to find $E(X)$. I claim that
$$
P(N=n) = 2^{-n}.
$$
Can you see why? Think about what the individual tosses must be. And now evaluate
$$
E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N=n)X(n).
$$

Comment: Thanks! So is $P(N=n)$ the probability of getting the first heads on the $n$-th toss?

Comment: I think I got it now. $$E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^{10^6}2^{-n}2^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{10^6} \frac{1}{2}=5\cdot 10^5$$.
Since it costs $10^5$ to play this game. I will have $4 \cdot 10^5$ "long-term gain", so I should play this game.

Comment: Yes, perfect :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)