# Is there a name for the distribution of the number of consecutive Bernoulli trials before the first failure?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, sampling

I want to take samples from this discrete probability distribution of $n$, which I think is defined as:

$$\Pr(n=i) = p^i (1-p)$$

where $p$ is the probability of success in each independent Bernoulli trial.  I.e. the number of consecutive successful binomial trials before the first unsuccessful one (or vice versa).

If $n$ were finite then this would be easy because I could calculate $Pr(n=i)$ for all $n$ and then sample from it.

I'm assuming this is a well-known distribution with software tools and I just don't know it's name.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer in one of the comments on this other question: [Expected value of the number of flips until the first head](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1196452/563913)
> It should be mentioned, the name of this distribution is "the geometric distribution." See here for a table of common distributions. – JMoravitz Mar 19 '15 at 3:46 (Thank you @JMoravitz)