# Expected number of coin flips with biased coin until you get n heads in a row)

Tags: probability

We can find out how many trails we need on average to get n consecutive heads with the equation below:

$$A =\dfrac { p^{−n} − 1 } {1 − p}$$

So, for $n=6$ with an unbiased coin, we'd require 62 trials.

My question is, how to deal with a biased coin.

Putting a coin with a .9 probability of landing heads, says we need -8 trials.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What's $p$ meant to be in that equation?  Also, I think you meant $n=5$ if you want to get $62$.  And, in your last sentence, how many Heads are you seeking such that you get $-8$ trials? If $n$ is a positive integer then $.9^{-n}>1$ so $A$ should be $>0$.

Comment: As to the question, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364038/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-get-five-consecutive-heads) and adapt the recursion to the weighted case.

Comment: you need $62$ expected tosses for $5$ consecutive heads and not $6$. Also, you can substitute $p$ with a different probability than $0.5$ if it is not a fair coin. So I am not sure what you are seeking. Is it the proof of a generic case that you are seeking?