# Understand how to solve recurrence relation

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Ravi Pradeep's solution uses a recurrence relation, I am new to recurrence relations but would like to understand this part of the answer.

[Expected Number of Coin Tosses to Get Five Consecutive Heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364038/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-get-five-consecutive-heads)

Having looked into recurrence relations I know that the methodology is to:

1. Solve the homogeneous equation
2. Solve the particular equation
3. Find final equation using the initial conditions

but I am struggling to apply this to the problem at hand.

The recurrence relation is:

$E_n= 2E_{n-1}+2$.

The solution then proceeds as follows:

Define $f(n)=E_n+2$ with $f(0)=2$. So,

Why is $f(n)=E_n+2$ used rather than  $f(n)=2E_n+2$?

\begin{align}
f(n)&=2f(n-1) \\
\implies f(n)&=2^{n+1}
\end{align}

How is the $f(n)=2^{n+1}$ derived?

Therefore, $E_n = 2^{n+1}-2 = 2(2^n-1)$

Where does the minus two come from in the solution above?

For $n=5$, it will give us $2(2^5-1)=62$.

Comment: Your wording is slightly confusing, because you've mixed the given solution with your questions about it. Perhaps you could write the solution as given first, then explain which parts you're not sure about.

Comment: Note that $E_n = 2 E_{n-1} + 2 \implies E_n + 2 = 2E_{n-1} + 4$. If we let $F_n = E_n + 2$, then, $F_n$ satisfies $F_n = 2F_{n-1}$. Consequently, $F_n = 2^n F_0 = 2^{n+1}$, as $F_0 = 2$. This implies $E_n + 2 = 2^{n+1} \implies E_n = 2(2^{n} - 1)$.